# Crash immediately after launch when using global function

Tags: ios, swift, function, uitableview

I have just figured out the solution to [a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32831715/restore-view-state-without-animating-segue)
 I was having where restoring my app's state after reopening performed a segue animation that I didn't want.

The problem was that I had to change `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in the app delegate. The app no longer animates when restoring the state, however I now have a different problem.

I am using a function to get an RGB colour from a number passed to the function. I use this function for setting a view's background colour within each cell in my table view. It worked fine before I made this change, however now it crashes on this line:

```
    cell.timeBackgroundView.backgroundColor = getColorFromNumber(Int(ride.waitTime!)!)
```

I have checked to see that `ride.waitTime!` does not equal nil, which it doesn't. `getColorFromNumber` is declared globally just above one of my classes.

Anyone have any ideas why this is an issue? It seems as if the function is not yet 'loaded' when the app restores.

***EDIT:***

The crash is simply:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: Update your question with details about the crash.

Comment: I have done, but it's just `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`.

Comment: That's a start. Now use the debugger and figure out which value is `nil`. Then find out why it's `nil` and fix it.

Comment: Int() can fail and return nil too

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Within my `ride` class, I was encoding correctly, but I was decoding the `waitTime` attribute with the wrong key, and thus, it couldn't be converted to a color as the function expects an int.